# How can I load a keras-tuner project by name?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-tuner

I ran multiple projects using keras-tuner and named them. Now I can't figure out how to load the projects to check the best results of each one since the `tuner` is just the last run and I wanted to check the results with `models = tuner.get_best_models()`.

I named the projects `tuner = RandomSearch(... project_name='...')` but how can I load them by name now?

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar issue. Were you able to solve this? It is strange that there is no documentation on how to load the `oracle.json` from the trail directory